# In JS object. Why do the prototype and constructor keep getting nested inside of each other

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, prototypejs

Hi I created a class as below:

```
function Shape(){
     this.x = 0;
     this.y = 0;
}
```

Now in the Chrome console when I type Shape.prototype it has
**constructor property** which on expanding has a **prototype** and **__ proto __**(dunder proto points to the Object Base and the chain ends here, I get this point.

But the prototype property **upon expanding** contains constructor property and this chain goes on and on (constructor to prototype and prototype to constructor) . Why is this happening?

Is it because that .prototype and .constructor **keep pointing at each other** or is there something else going on over here? can please someone explain.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, they are two objects pointing at each other. There's no infinite amount of objects, just a circular reference.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the question. I tried searching for a similar question but couldn't find it. Another quick query why does the constructor's dunder proto point to a f:{} (shape object) wheareas the prototype's dunder proto point to base Object.

Comment: Because the constructor (function) inherits from `Function.prototype`

Comment: Thank you, this makes complete sense now. Because functions are first class objects and the function prototype inherits from the Object base again.